# Adding button to ArcPad form

Tags: arcpad, vbscript

I am trying to add a button to an ArcPad form that sets the values to Cereal and Corn. This is as far as I have gotten and I am stuck.

---

I Made apl that has a form. I get the values into the form using the arcpad data manager from ArcMap. it populates the form giving me combo boxes. What I need is a button that will make it easier to choose specific values from the combo boxes. So instead of scrolling down the combo boxes to make my choice and hitting OK. I want to just hit the corn button and then that updates the combo boxes and adds the form and closes it.
In the image you can understand what it is I need to do. This is for field work and the easier it is to insert some crop types the faster it gets done.

```vb
'once called updates the fields to add in corn to the form then closes the form
Sub InsertCorn(ByVal layerName, ByVal pageName)

   Dim objEditForm
   Dim objTheLayer 
   Dim objEFPageControls
   Set objTheLayer = Application.Map.Layers.item(layerName)
   Set objEditForm = objTheLayer.Forms(1)
   Set objEFPageControls= objEditForm.Pages(pageName).Controls

   objEFPageControls("cboAGRLU_ClassGRP").value = "Cereal"
   objEFPageControls("cboCropType_Varietal").value = "Corn"

   Set objEFPageControls= Nothing
   Set objEditForm = Nothing
   Set objTheLayer = Nothing
End sub
```

then in the onclick event on the button:

```
  Call InsertCorn("Corn", "PAGE1")
```

[image: ArcPad Form]

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to say. Is this a Sub that is called by an _onClick_ event? You say sets the value, value  of what? What type of control is cboAGRLU_ClassGRP? Please update your question.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the ArcPad layer name that you are applying the value update to and call your Sub via onClick event per @Hornbydd comment, see example code below:

```
Sub InsertCorn(ByVal layerName, ByVal pageName)

  Dim objEditForm, objTheLayer, objEFPageControls
  Set objTheLayer = Application.Map.Layers.item(layerName)
  Set objEditForm = objTheLayer.Forms(1)
  Set objEFPageControls= objEditForm.Pages(pageName).Controls

  objEFPageControls("cboAGRLU_ClassGRP").value = "Cereal"
  objEFPageControls("cboCropType_Varietal").value = "Corn"

  Set objEFPageControls= Nothing
  Set objEditForm = Nothing
  Set objTheLayer = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh I thought since there is only one form and one page that it would know. Also by calling it via sub what is it that you mean? Inside the button I have it calling InsertCorn on the OnClick command. Also what would i insert for layername?

Comment: @abhinav sharma, The name of the layer that is related to your form in ArcPad.  For example, my sub example is passing in the layeName and pageName as arguments.

Comment: So when i call insert corn from the onclick command i would do it as Call InsertCorn(corn,Page1)? I will try it out thank you

Comment: Yes, I believe you will need double quotes around those two, e.g. ("corn","Page1")

Comment: using this method I am getting a runtime error. with the message being  "Object required: 'objTheLayer'" at the line where it sets objthelayer

Comment: Can you post your updated code to your question and the onClick call?

Comment: Okay updated the question.

Comment: Is corn the name of the layer in the ArcPad>Properties layer list.  In addition, you will have to change the one to zero if you are only dealing with one form Set objEditForm = objTheLayer.Forms(0) or just provide the form name instead.

Comment: So in the table of contents on arcpad it only has the map layer so in this case the file name used for the arcmap data transfer. I will set the 1 to zero and change the layer name to the layer name in the table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

Finally have it working error free. This is the finished code. Seems to do all that i as for it. Thank you very much artwork21 for all your help.

```
Sub InsertCrop(Byval className, Byval cropName)
  Dim objEditForm
  Dim objTheLayer 
  Dim objEFPageControls
  Set objTheLayer = Application.Map.Layers.item("STB_EOS_DCT")
  Set objEditForm = objTheLayer.Forms("EDITFORM")
  Set objEFPageControls= objEditForm.Pages("PAGE1").Controls

  objEFPageControls("cboAGRLU_ClassGRP").value = className
  objEFPageControls("cboCropType_Varietal").value = cropName
  objEFPageControls("txtFIELDNOTES").value = ""

 objEditForm.Close(True)
 Set objEFPageControls= Nothing
 Set objEditForm = Nothing
 Set objTheLayer = Nothing

End sub
```